# dc.js - plotting large data sets and multiple series on same chart w/ different rendering styles (line, bar, etc)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have been using dimple.js for sometime and i do like it.  however for large sets of data i am noticing some performance issues and would like to try crossfilter + dc to see how it performs.  My problem is i am not quite sure how to best package the payload before delivering to the page/javascript.

my json is somewhat complex, but at the core of it, it contains an array of data sets that i want to plot on the same chart as line or bar charts.  so for example, below, i would like to plot the first two sets (Open and Close) as line series and the third series as a barchart (ideally on a 2nd y-axis).

my questions are:
Is this possible with dc.js?
Do i get any benefits of crossfilter in this case with regards to page load speed (the real data will consists of 6 arrays and about 3k data points each).?

Here is what the json looks like:

```
{
    "hist_quotes" : [{
            "title" : "Open Prices",
            "data" : [{
                    "y" : 4318.28,
                    "x" : "2014-12-05 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 4309.48,
                    "x" : "2014-12-04 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 4312.17,
                    "x" : "2014-12-03 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 4291.33,
                    "x" : "2014-12-02 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }
            }],
            [{
            "title" : "Close Prices",
            "data" : [{
                    "y" : 4324.28,
                    "x" : "2014-12-05 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 4355.48,
                    "x" : "2014-12-04 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 4333.17,
                    "x" : "2014-12-03 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 4334.33,
                    "x" : "2014-12-02 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }
            }],
            [{
            "title" : "Volume",
            "data" : [{
                    "y" : 431828000,
                    "x" : "2014-12-05 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 401828000,
                    "x" : "2014-12-04 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 431828000,
                    "x" : "2014-12-03 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }, {
                    "y" : 401828000,
                    "x" : "2014-12-02 00:00:00",
                    "category" : "Open"
                }
            }]
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you're only creating one chart, then crossfilter/dc probably don't make sense. They're designed for "dimensional charting" which generally means you have a data set with several characteristics (dimensions) that you want to show in separate charts.

Comment: And if all you want to do is create a single chart that has a couple of line charts and a bar chart, plain old D3.js is all you need.

Comment: Crossfilter can help aggregate the data, though.  Most charting libraries will have about the same performance characteristics because the limiting factor is the number of DOM elements.  (The only exception is if you can use canvas rendering, but that's pretty difficult.)  You want to find some way to summarize the data, and crossfilter can do it, although it's by no means the only way.

Comment: Since you're talking about using the same chart, you may be looking for the [composite chart](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#composite-chart).  You mention the second axis this would be [compositeChart.rightY](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#rightyyscale) and various other methods with "right" in them.

Comment: Thank you.  I will have a try as one of the functional requirements is to provide zoom, which seems to be built-in w/ this library